# BulletMicroChart with positive and negative threshold values and alternatives

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm trying to implement a threshold bar that could go either side, using 0 as starting point ideally in the middle of that bar.
UI5 has the BulletMicroChart, which has the threshold property and everything, however, it's clearly documented it doesn't support negative numbers, and if any is bound to it, it just adds it to 0 to the left corner of the bar.

I'm sure I saw in the past SAP had a threshold bar chart that would work as I described above, but when checking the samples I cannot find anything closer than the bullet chart.

This is what I was looking for (Figma SAP stencils has it): [image: threshold]

Any suggestions on how to better tackle this? Extending a chart seems complicated/overhead, would that be the only alternative within the UI5 library aside from looking for other JS libs?

Thanks.